# How to add quick launch menu to SharePoint 2013 custom Master page?

Tags: custom-masterpage, quick-launch

We have applied a custom Master page to our SP2013 sites. The master page have removed the OOB quick launch menu at the left. In the same position, a custom navigation menu webpart is placed.

Some users said they want the OOB quick launch menu show up in the system pages. It is particular useful when they edit the site permission. Because all the permission group will show up at the left quick launch menu which is a lot easier.

However, in the custom Master page I found the OOB quick launch bar is not hided but simply not existing. I refer to v5.Master and try to copy & paste over the  tab but several system pages are throwing error.

What can I do? Any quick way to fix it?
I am also looking for good online material teach me how to do. Many thanks for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the left menu again. I think it is a dirty code. But I will post here for future reference.

```
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBar" runat="server">

                                                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarTop" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchTop" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftNavBarDataSource" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderCalendarNavigator" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server" />
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderQuickLaunchBottom" runat="server" />
                                                            <ContentTemplate>
                                                                <ul class="s4-specialNavLinkList">
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                                                                            runat="server"
                                                                            NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/recyclebin.aspx"
                                                                            ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
                                                                            ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png"
                                                                            ImageWidth=16
                                                                            ImageHeight=16
                                                                            OffsetX=0
                                                                            OffsetY=428
                                                                            id="idNavLinkRecycleBin"
                                                                            Text="<%$Resources:wss,StsDefault_RecycleBin%>"
                                                                            CssClass="s4-rcycl"
                                                                            PermissionsString="DeleteListItems" />
                                                                    </li>
                                                                    <li>
                                                                        <SharePoint:ClusteredSPLinkButton
                                                                            id="idNavLinkViewAllV4"
                                                                            runat="server"
                                                                            PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                                                                            NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx"
                                                                            ImageClass="s4-specialNavIcon"
                                                                            ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/fgimg.png"
                                                                            ImageWidth=16
                                                                            ImageHeight=16
                                                                            OffsetX=0
                                                                            OffsetY=0
                                                                            Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_short%>"
                                                                            accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>"/>
                                                                    </li>
                                                                </ul>
                                                            </ContentTemplate>                                                              
                                                            <SharePoint:SPNavigationManager
                                                                                                            id="TreeViewNavigationManagerV4"
                                                                            runat="server"
                                                                            ContainedControl="TreeView"
                                                                            CssClass="ms-tv-box"
                                                                        >
                                                                            <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx" id="idNavLinkSiteHierarchyV4" Text="<%$Resources:wss,treeview_header%>" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_AK%>" CssClass="ms-tv-header" />
                                                                                <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TreeViewAndDataSource">
                                                                                    <Template_Controls>
                                                                                    <SharePoint:SPHierarchyDataSourceControl
                                                                                        runat="server"
                                                                                        id="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                                                                        RootContextObject="Web"
                                                                                        IncludeDiscussionFolders="true"
                                                                                    />
                                                                                    <SharePoint:SPRememberScroll runat="server" id="TreeViewRememberScrollV4" onscroll="javascript:_spRecordScrollPositions(this);"
                                                                                        style="overflow: auto;">
                                                                                        <SharePoint:SPTreeView
                                                                                        id="WebTreeViewV4"
                                                                                        runat="server"
                                                                                        ShowLines="false"
                                                                                        DataSourceId="TreeViewDataSourceV4"
                                                                                        ExpandDepth="0"
                                                                                        SelectedNodeStyle-CssClass="TREEVIEWSELECTEDCLASS"
                                                                                        NodeStyle-CssClass="TREEVIEWNODECLASS"
                                                                                        SkipLinkText=""
                                                                                        NodeIndent="12"
                                                                                        ExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosed.png?rev=23"
                                                                                        ExpandImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvclosedrtl.png?rev=23"
                                                                                        CollapseImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopen.png?rev=23"
                                                                                        CollapseImageUrlRtl="/_layouts/15/images/tvopenrtl.png?rev=23"
                                                                                        NoExpandImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/tvblank.gif?rev=23"
                                                                                        >
                                                                                        </SharePoint:SPTreeView>
                                                                                    </SharePoint:SPRememberScroll>
                                                                                    </Template_Controls>
                                                                                </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                                                                        </SharePoint:SPNavigationManager>


                                            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                        </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Above code will put recycle bin and view All site content button at the left menu.